# xamarin forms svg files show on android emulator but not in mobile device htc one m9 android 7

Tags: android, xamarin, svg, ffimageloading

MainActivity.cs :

```
CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: false); SvgCachedImage.Init();
```

MainView.xaml

```
xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
<ff:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="100" Source="resource://Sanaap.App.Images.SosRequest.svg"/>
```

(Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms 2.3.6 &
xamarin 4.10)

svg files show on android emulator Xamarin Forms project (android).
but not in mobile device htc one m9 android 7 (show nothing).
Why?

Comment: Did you set your svg file property: Build action => EmbeddedResource ?

Comment: Yes I did. It shows in emulator.

Comment: Emulator can "find" pictures but not automatically in runtime... On which device are you trying ? ios or android ? have you tried all these points: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support#xamarinforms

Comment: Android 7 HTC one m9